# Bad baselines with two columns of different font sizes in beamer

Tags: beamer, columns

I want a two-column view for a beamer frame: one with text in one size/face, the other with text in another size/face, such that the baselines of the first lines in both columns align, but each column has its usual baseline spacing. Seems like `\begin{columns}[t]` is the thing to do for this, and it looks like that first line is indeed lined up right, but the next line is too close to the first. With other font faces, it can look even worse.

For example:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\setbeamerfont{leftfont}{size*={16pt}{5pt}}
\setbeamerfont{rightfont}{size*={52pt}{5pt}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\begin{columns}[t]
\column{.3\textwidth}
\usebeamerfont{leftfont}The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
\column{.8\textwidth}
\usebeamerfont{rightfont}Jackdaws love my big sphinx of quartz.
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

How can I work around this? I don't want to just `\begin{columns}[T]`, since that looks completely different. Actually, I wonder if columns is irrelevant and the problem is in the baselineskip in `\setbeamerfont`

Comment: Yes! Turns out I arrived at the same conclusion :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, the baselineskip should be larger than the fontszie.  Using 5pt with a 52pt font is definitely too small.

In addition the default computer modern font does not provide the exact sizes you requested. If you actually want the sizes you asked for, use a freely scalable font like latin modern:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

\usepackage{lmodern}
\setbeamerfont{leftfont}{size*={16}{19}}
\setbeamerfont{rightfont}{size*={52}{62}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\begin{columns}[t]
\begin{column}{.3\textwidth}
\usebeamerfont{leftfont}The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
\end{column}
\begin{column}{.8\textwidth}
\usebeamerfont{rightfont}Jackdaws love my big sphinx of quartz.
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]